# maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

This problem compute to showing cource.

Fie tosses of a coin with P(head)=p resulted in H,T,T,T,T.

```
    1) Write the likelihood function L(p).



    2) Compute the maximum likelihood estimate of p.
```

Comment: Have you at least put an effort to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For (1) the probability of H is $p$ and of T is $(1-p)$ so if the tosses are independent then it is clearly $$p\times (1-p)\times (1-p)\times (1-p)\times (1-p)$$ which you can simplify slightly.

For (2) you are looking for the value of $p$ which maximises this expression, so start by take the derivative with respect to $p$ and find the value(s) of $p$ which make the derivative zero.  As a hint, this may be easier if you do **not** multiply out the expression first.

Comment: umm..(2) is (0.5)/5 ?? correct??

Comment: No: if you try your $p=0.5/5=0.1$ then you get $0.1 \times 0.9^4 = 0.06561$ while if you try $p=0.11$ you get about $0.069$ which is bigger, so $0.1$ is not the maximum likelihood estimate (nor is $0.11$).  Try editing your question to show your working and we can point out errors.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to not multiply out the expression first